# Suddenly can't access samba share from windows 10 file explorer after it was previously working Ubuntu Sever 20.4

Tags: networking, server, ssh, samba, file-sharing

I got ubuntu server up and running perfectly, everything is working exactly as intended. I was doing a file transfer to move all the things I wanted to back up, the exchange finished and a few hours later I noticed I could no longer connect to my Samba share folder from my computer anymore

I have literally changed nothing and I'm not sure what to do
steps I've taken to solve the issue that haven't worked:

restarted Windows client twice

quit my SSH session on Windows Client connected to Ubuntu Server

restarted Ubuntu Server twice

confirmed I typed in the IP address correctly

example address format I was using to connect //192.168.1.382

checked samba config file to make sure nothing was altered, nothing was

someone said to add this line to the config file did not work

```
server min protocol = NT1
```

I'm new to manager servers and working over Samba

Comment: Glad you fixed it but there is no Ubuntu version 20.4

Answer (score 0):

solution:

use double \  instead of double /

I'm an idiot I know feel free to laugh at me, got too used to using Linux

Comment: I missed a 0 thank you for notifying me